# Open URL from Google Drive Directly to Updated File

Tags: google-drive

I download periodically updated spreadsheets from one URL from a remote website.

I want to be able to download the spreadsheet using Google Drive and the URL.  I'd like to either:

1. Have that URL listed in my filenames on Google Drive or
2. Open a file and automatically update the old file while keeping the same filename.

This would have Google Sheets function like MS Office that saves a list of recently opened files and the user can "pin" a recently opened URL that downloads and opens the hosted file, which can then be discarded after opening the file without it saved.

This [forum question](https://superuser.com/questions/737749/downloading-from-internet-directly-to-google-drive)'s solution, "[Save to Google Drive](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/save-to-google-drive/gmbmikajjgmnabiglmofipeabaddhgne)," I believe only saves the file creating a new one for each update rather than automatically saving and replacing.

Is there a way to accomplish this on Google Drive without?